# android volley post parameter and receive json

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

i am fairly new to android development, i am trying to make a android volley request which send an ID to the php service and if it matches on the server side it should return all the value associated to it in json which is then recieved on the android app and displayed. any help will appreciated

```
<?php

require("include/config.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $query = " SELECT * FROM music WHERE musicID = :ID  " ;

    $query_params = array(
        ':ID' => $_POST['ID'],


            );

    try {
        $statement   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $statement->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {


        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "  error";
        die(json_encode($response));

    }

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    if($result){

            $return =array();

            foreach($result as $rows){
        $json = array();
        $json["title"] = $rows["title"];
        $json["rating"]= $rows["rating"];
        $json["Price"] = $rows["Price"];
        $json["Description"] = $rows["Description"];

        array_push ($return,$json);



            }
     echo stripcslashes(json_encode($datareturn, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));








    }




} else {
}

?>
```

**android volley request**

```
 JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                    try{
                        JSONObject obj=response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Item item=new Item();
                        item.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                        item.setImage(obj.getString("image"));


                        //add to array
                        array.add(item);
                    }catch(JSONException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        AppController.getmInstance().addToRequesQueue(jsonArrayRequest,ID);
```

Comment: What are the problems you are facing?

Comment: i am not getting anything back from the server e.g. item array is empty. cant figure out what exactly is going wrong. i double check the script with html form and it works fine. so something wrong in the java code request

Comment: how are you recieving `ID` field on your server? In RequestBody or in the url path.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you have a `POST` request, and unfortunately, there is no direct `constructor` in volley to send the `POST` request for `JsonArray`.

> the android volley team maybe add it later but for now you can do this :

**Step 1** : Create your class and extends `JsonArrayRequest` then you should override.

```
public class CustomJsonArrayRequest extends JsonArrayRequest {
    public CustomJsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
    }
}
```

**Step 2** : Now that you have a constructor to send the request you can easily send your request using it.

```
//If you are sending ID inside request body
JsonObject requestJson = new JsonObject();
requestJson.put("ID", "Your ID Value");

CustomJsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new CustomJsonArrayRequest(RequestMethod.POST,URL, requestJson, Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override 
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                try{ 
                    JSONObject obj=response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item item=new Item();
                    item.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                    item.setImage(obj.getString("image"));


                    //add to array 
                    array.add(item);
                }catch(JSONException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } 
            } 
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        } 
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        } 
    }); 
    AppController.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Also, you need to pass this ID in the url.

Let me know if you need to ask anything else. :)

Comment: the class i have already extends baseactivity, so do i need to create a new class called CustomeJsonArray?

Comment: Yeah! Create new class CustomJsonArrayRequest! Also tell me where you want have your `ID` field?

Comment: OK. The ID is passed onto this activity from the previous activity  using intent.putextra  and I am storing it as a string.

Comment: How are you passing it to the server? Also let me know if it works?

Comment: That's the part I am struggling with, all I am doing now it adding it to request but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh can your paste your POST request URL? On which you are posting your call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107566/discussion-between-dave-ranjan-and-wazz-khan).